# Numbering only 2nd level headings in an org file

Tags: org-mode

I would like to be able to turn on numbering when exporting an org file, but only in second level headings. First level and all other levels should remain unnumbered.

I.e.

* Unnumbered

** Numbered

*** Unnumbered

**** Unnumbered

How can I achieve this effect in a specific document?

Comment: THe answer to this is almost certainly going to depend on what format you’re exporting to. For example, if you’re exporting to HTML, then you can probably include some CSS to disable the numbering of top–level list items, while leaving the others alone. But it’ll be something else for PDF or LaTeX or anything else you might be exporting to.

Comment: I am happy with odt

Comment: As @db48x points out, this is a mattter for the backend: Org mode itself cannot do that, since it depends on the backend for numbering sections. It's not even clear that every backend can do it (e.g. I don't think LaTeX can). Note that that makes the question out of scope for Emacs SE.